# I am an engineer by qualification. But want to do a PhD in marketing. Is it possible? Or am I day dreaming?

Tags: phd

I wish to get into a PhD program at a US/Canada university in marketing. I have five years experience in international marketing. By qualification, I am an engineer. I graduated from LSU with a masters degree in Electrical Engineering.

I have a little research experience of about 8 months, but that was in electrical engineering.

With this background, will it be possible for me to get into a PhD program in marketing at all? I know what I want to research on, and I am sure I can prepare a decent SOP. But will that be enough? I am targeting fall 2017.

Comment: _I have five years experience in international marketing._ I believe it is do-able. Good luck !

Comment: Take a look at the Technical Entrepreneurship program at Univ Rochester.  I think Duke may offer something similar

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on where you apply. One question an admission committee would have is your academic preparation. If your transcripts show marketing prerequisites it will help tremendously.

Practical experience is valuable but a PhD requires basic knowledge in the common theories of the field.